# Angular: Update Route Data

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular 5 application that uses `ngx-breadcrumbs`. The breadcrumb is set as data inside a route, as such:

```
{ path: 'event-template', component: EventTemplateComponent, data: { breadcrumbs: 'New Event'} }
```

I want to update this breadcrumb later from within a component, as such:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((currentData) => {
    currentData['breadcrumbs'] = 'newValue';
  });
}
```

Obviously, I want the value of the breadcrumb to be updated before the page loads. So that the new string takes precedence. But I don't know how to do this and I don't think the approach above is necessarily correct. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: The data on the route is static. It cannot be changed.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to update the data on the breadcrumb without triggering a routing event?  One way would be to trigger the router again with a `router.navigate('event-template', {breadcrumbs: 'New Event'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than assigning a new value on the routing params it would be better to trigger another routing event using the `router.navigate` method. You could do something like `this.router.navigate('event-template', {breadcrumbs: 'New Event'})`

Comment: Hello, zmanc. Thanks for your comment. Sadly, this doesn't actually work because of `ngx-breadcrumbs`. I try the following: `this.router.navigate(['/events/event-template'], { breadcrumbs: 'New Event' } )` and I get this error: `Argument of type '{ breadcrumbs: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'breadcrumbs' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.` Yet, the required module is properly loaded in the appropriate router. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hello. The 'NavigationExtras' should be {data: '{ breadcrumbs: string; }' }